# Lost all email composed and sent while in airplane mode

Tags: iphone, ios, airplane-mode

I just returned from an international flight that did not feature wifi access. While my iPhone was in airplane mode, I replied to a number of email messages attached to my exchange account and sent them while offline.

Once landed and connected back to my cellular network, I realized that there was no trace of the sent messages or replies; neither in Drafts, Outbox nor the Sent Items folder.

A quick Google search indicates that this [may have](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5608684?start=0&tstart=0) been [an issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4345457?start=0&tstart=0) in the past. Are those messages simply lost at this point?

Comment: Exchange uses a temp folder called "outbox" they may be stuck there. Typically pressing Send puts the message in Outbox, and when it's actually been sent then it moves from Outbox to Sent.

Comment: I'll clarify: There was nothing in _Outbox_ either.